# Put a value outside a Function in a global var

Tags: javascript, scope, global

I'm sorry guys, the entire code is this. I given you the short form to be light, but I made many mistakes. So please, ignore the code written before and read this.

At the bottom of the code you can find also the calls to the functions (They are in two other files.html)

The problem is that the value that the three "window.alert" show (during the running of the second Function) is undefined, as there aren't the three declared var on top or they aren't global (var numero_giocatori; var numero_lupi; var numero_villici;)

(I'm sorry, I changed the edit many times. Please be nice with a newbie guy ;-) )

```
enter code here
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//              IMPOSTAZIONI: NUMERO DI GIOCATORI                       //
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

var numero_giocatori;
var numero_lupi;
var numero_villici;

function validatore_numero_giocatori(numero_giocatori) {

var scritta_output;

    numero_giocatori = document.getElementById("digitazione_numero_giocatori").value;

        if (numero_giocatori < 8 || numero_giocatori > 24) {
            scritta_output = "Hai inserito un numero minore di 8 o maggiore di 24";
        } 
        else if (isNaN(numero_giocatori)) {
            scritta_output = "Non hai inserito un numero. <br> Inserire un numero da 8 a 24";
        }
        else {
            scritta_output = "OK!";
            alert(numero_giocatori);
            window.open("/home/enrico/Scrivania/cod-x/lup-x/gioco/impostazioni: numero lupi vs numero villici.html","_self");
        }
        document.getElementById("validazione").innerHTML = scritta_output;
    return numero_giocatori;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//              IMPOSTAZIONI: NUMERO DI LUPI VS VILLICI                                                         //
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

function scelta_modalità_di_selezione (numero_giocatori) {
    if (document.getElementById("proporzioni_random").checked){             //proporzionale random
        numero_lupi = Math.floor(Math.round(Math.random()*1) + numero_giocatori/4); //osservare bene il codice!!!
        numero_villici = numero_giocatori - numero_lupi;
        alert(numero_giocatori);
        alert(numero_lupi);
        alert(numero_villici);
        }
    else{
        alert("Ciao, ti ricordi di me?");
    }
    window.open("/home/enrico/Scrivania/cod-x/lup-x/gioco/impostazioni: creazione personaggi.html","_self");
}
//FIRST CALL HTML
<div id = "form1">
    Numero Giocatori:<input type="text" name="numero" id="digitazione_numero_giocatori"><br><br>
    <div>   
    Inserire un numero di giocatori da 8 a 24   
    <p id="validazione"></p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="validatore_numero_giocatori(numero_giocatori)">Avanti</button>
</div>

//SECOND CALL HTML
 <div id = "form2">
        Seleziona la modalità di gioco<br>
        <div>
        Random. lupi circa 1/4:<input type="checkbox" id="proporzioni_random"><br>
        Digita il numero dei lupi:<input type="text" id="proporzioni_a_scelta">
        </div>
        <button type="button" onclick="scelta_modalità_di_selezione()">Avanti</button>
</div>
```

Comment: where do you get `scritta_output` from?

Comment: Where are you calling `scelta_modalità_di_selezione`? Where do you think you are changing the value of `numero_giocatori`?

Comment: `validatore_numero_giocatori()` is called `onclick` of the button without any arguments. This is also your function signature, therefore `numero_giocatori` will be undefined. You declared it in the global scope, else you'd have gotten a  `ReferenceError`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I used a shorter code to not give you too much to read.

1. "scritta_output" is not a problem, in the long code it works.

2. "scelta_modalità_di_selezione" is called in another HTML file. The same file I open using:
window.open("/home/enrico/Scrivania/cod-x/lup-x/gioco/impostazioni: numero lupi vs numero villici.html","_self");

Comment: so, what's the question now, where are you stuck? :D

Comment: I'm sorry, the before code was full of mistake. (I give you a short version to be light). Now I re-edit the entire code. ;-)

Comment: @EnricoLaSpina It's okay but your problem is not clear. Where is it? and what is it?

Comment: The problem is that the value that the three "window.alert" show (during the running of the second Function) is undefined, as there aren't the three declared var on top or they aren't global (var numero_giocatori; var numero_lupi; var numero_villici;)

Comment: Nobody has the solution?
I've bother you with all my changes? :-)

Comment: Is there anybody out there?!
I think I know what's the problem!!!
The problem is that global var are not useful after a "window.open" command.
So the value of my global var (when i call the second function is setted on undefined. and That's all.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function validatore_numero_giocatori(numero_giocatori) {
  alert(numero_giocatori);
window.open("/home/enrico/Scrivania/cod-x/lup-x/gioco/impostazioni: numero lupi vs numero villici.html","_self");
document.getElementById("validazione").innerHTML = scritta_output;
return numero_giocatori;
  }
```

You need to pass the var "numero_giocatori" to the function.

function validatore_numero_giocatori(**numero_giocatori**)

Then call it like this:

validatore_numero_giocatori(numero_giocatori)

Comment: Thank you
I've tried to put "(numero_giocatori)" as argument and to add also in the call (as you suggest) but it doesn't work.

I've re-post the code because pasting it (the first time) I made some mistake. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute your function with this: 
You need to access the value of the input element.

```
function validatore_numero_giocatori() {
  numero_giocatori = document.getElementById('digitazione_numero_giocatori').value;
  alert(numero_giocatori);
  window.open("/home/enrico/Scrivania/cod-x/lup-x/gioco/impostazioni: numero lupi vs numero villici.html","_self");
  document.getElementById("validazione").innerHTML = scritta_output;
  return numero_giocatori;
}
```

Comment: You are right, I just used. I made a mistake pasting the code.
Above you can find the right code. 
I'm sorry.