# How to use the same global var throw the windows

Tags: javascript, global, window.open

I haven't fixed my problem shown on the following link.

[Put a value outside a Function in a global var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36790858/put-a-value-outside-a-function-in-a-global-var?noredirect=1#comment61158542_36790858)

The point is simply this:
when I open a new window (using the window.open() command), the new window don't knows the value of the global var setted on the preview window.
There's a way to let aware the second window of this value?

Thanks for read and sorry for my errors in language.
Thanks for read and sorry for my bad language.

Comment: Here is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/87737/804847

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I pass a JavaScript variable to another browser window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87359/can-i-pass-a-javascript-variable-to-another-browser-window)

Comment: Thank you, I was getting crazy!!!